# Curl 77 Error setting certificate file: http_ca.crt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm getting the error: `Curl: 77 Error setting certificate file: http_ca.crt`

when running the line: `curl --cacert http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200`

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error and more importantly how to resolve it?

I'm attempting to follow the steps in the below link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

**Edit:**

The website says to use:

`docker cp es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .`

from my understanding /user/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt is the source file inside the docker container, however when going into the docker container using `docker exec -it es01 bash` and using the `ls` command there is no 'usr' folder???? Did I miss a step? Is the tutorial wrong?

[image]

**Edit 2**

So I found out that `docker cp es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .` does copy the file to my Home directory (still no clue how though since I couldn't find the 'usr' folder in the docker container).
The original error of curl 77 is still there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong...

I needed to give myself (root) permission to access the http_ca.crt file.

Answer (score 0):

For me was the same issue but I managed to solve it with the change of the destination folder's permission to write permission to others.